# Why does crossvalind fail?

Tags: matlab

I am using cross valind function on a very small data... However I observe that it gives me incorrect results for the same. Is this supposed to happen ?

I have Matlab R2012a and here is my output

```
crossvalind('KFold',1:1:11,5)

ans =

 2
 5
 1
 3
 2
 1
 5
 3
 5
 1
 5
```

Notice the absence of `set 4`.. Is this a bug ? I expected atleast 2 elements per set but it gives me 0 in one... and it happens a lot that is the values are not uniformly distributed in the sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help for [crossvalind](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html) says that the form you are using is: `crossvalind(METHOD, GROUP, ...)`. In this case, GROUP is the e.g. the class labels of your data. So 1:11 as the second argument is confusing here, because it suggests no two examples have the same label. I think this is sufficiently unusual that you shouldn't be surprised if the function does something strange.

I tried doing:

```
numel(unique(crossvalind('KFold', rand(11, 1) > 0.5, 5)))
```

and it reliably gave `5` as a result, which is what I would expect; my example would correspond to a two-class problem (I would guess that, as a general rule, you'd want something like `numel(unique(group)) <= numel(group) / folds`) - my hypothesis would be that it tries to have one example of each class in the Kth fold, and at least 2 examples in every other, with a difference between fold sizes of no more than 1 - but I haven't looked in the code to verify this.

It is possible that you mean to do:

```
crossvalind('KFold', 11, 5);
```

which would compute 5 folds for 11 data points - this doesn't attempt to do anything clever with labels, so you would be sure that there will be K folds.

However, in your problem, if you really have very few data points, then it is probably better to do leave-one-out cross validation, which you could do with:

```
crossvalind('LeaveMOut', 11, 1);
```

although a better method would be:

```
for leave_out=1:11
  fold_number = (1:11) ~= leave_out;
  <code here; where fold_number is 0, this is the leave-one-out example. fold_number = 1 means that the example is in the main fold.>
end
```